# Drop duplicates based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5, 10],[8, 40],[8, 50],[10, 390], [10, 395], [10, 405], [11, 390], [11, 395], [11, 405], [13, 390], [13, 395], [13, 405]], columns=['index', 'so_id'])
```

| index | so_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 |
| 8 | 40 |
| 8 | 50 |
| 10 | 390 |
| 10 | 395 |
| 10 | 405 |
| 11 | 390 |
| 11 | 395 |
| 11 | 405 |
| 13 | 390 |
| 13 | 395 |
| 13 | 405 |

The desired output would be the following:

| index | so_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 |
| 8 | 40 |
| 10 | 390 |
| 11 | 395 |
| 13 | 405 |

Basically my goal is to drop duplicates on the column 'index' while keeping a **different** ascending value for the column 'so_id'.

The key point is that I don't want a simple drop_duplicates on the variable 'index' since this would get me the same 'so_id' after the drop_duplicates. I want drop_duplicates on 'index' and at the same time get the different values of the column 'so_id'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values are sorted, you can do:

```
seen = set()


def fn(x):
    for val in x:
        if val in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(val)
        return val


df = df.groupby("index")["so_id"].apply(fn).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index  so_id
0      5     10
1      8     40
2     10    390
3     11    395
4     13    405
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat brute force but will find a solution even if a simplistic 'take first available number' strategy leads into a dead end (so more general). Also will tell you if a solution cannot be found (as may well be the case):

```
n_tries = 1000
for _ in range(n_tries):
    df2 = df.groupby('index').apply(lambda g:g.sample(n=1))
    if df2['so_id'].is_unique:
        print('solution\n',df2)
        break
else:
    print('no solution found')
```

output

```
solution
          index  so_id
index                
5     0      5     10
8     2      8     50
10    5     10    405
11    7     11    395
13    9     13    390
```